# Define all pure virtual functions in abstract base class as a varaidaic template

Tags: c++, abstract-class, variadic-templates, pure-virtual

Can a single variadic function handle all base class pure virtual functions? In the case below`Say` would override  `SayGreeting` and `SayGreetingLocation`.

```
class  Brain {

 private:
  virtual void SayGreeting(std::string greeting) = 0;
  virtual void SayGreetingLocation(std::string greeting, std::string location) = 0;
}

class Mouth: public Brain {

 public:
  Say(){}
  template<typename T, typename... Args>
  void Say(T first, Args... args) {
    std::cout << first;
    Say(args...)
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to override `Brain::SayGreeting` with `Mouth::Say` ? Your example does not explain what you want to do because there is no inheritance (and a mouth isn't really a brain) and `Say` is completely unrelated to `SayGreeting` (and there is a couple of typos)

Comment: Don't understand your question, but member function templates cannot be virtual, if this is what you ask.

Comment: I would like Say to override SayGreeting and SayGreetingLocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. Member function templates cannot be virtual and to override a method in the base class the method needs to have the same name and signature. But you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class  Brain {    
private:
    virtual void SayGreeting(const std::string& greeting) = 0;
    virtual void SayGreetingLocation(const std::string& greeting,const std::string& location) = 0;
};

class Mouth: public Brain {    
    template<typename... Args>
    void Say(Args... args) {
        (std::cout << ... << args);
    }
public:
    void SayGreeting(const std::string& greeting) override {
        Say(greeting);
    }
    void SayGreetingLocation(const std::string& greeting, const std::string& location) override {
        Say(greeting,location);
    }
};
```

There are a couple of mistakes in your code: Missing `;`, `std::cout << args` should be `std::cout << first` you either need to stop the recursion somehow or not use recursion in the first place. Since C++17 many recursions for templates can be replaced with [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

PS: This is perhaps just an example, but your inheritance looks odd. A `Mouth` is not a `Brain` but public inheritance does model a "is-a" relation.

Comment: Shouldn't `std::cout << args` rather be `std::cout << first;`?

Comment: @StafanKssmr indeed, i simply copied OPs code without adressing any other issue than the one that was asked for. Will fix that

Comment: @StefanKssmr admittedly I was just too lazy and didnt want to add code without testing it, but you are right, will do it

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you already wrote "you need to terminate the recursion somehow". My bad.

Comment: @StefanKssmr no worries, I sometimes need to be pushed a bit to write a good answer ;)

Comment: I hope all my typos are cleaned up.  Sorry about that :(

Comment: @SwaT no they are not, but anyhow you shouldnt fix problems in your question after you got answers. When you edit your question to fix problems addressed in the answer then the answer is pointless

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way to do this automatically, which I assume is what you're asking. I'm not sure there's even a sensible macro hack that can semi-automate it.

Manually forwarding the arguments to the implementation of `Say` is of course straightforward:

```
void Mouth::SayGreetingLocation(std::string greeting, std::string location)
{
    this->Say(greeting, location);
}
```

Some asides:

- Your `Say()` funnction will need a 0-parameter "terminating" overload.
- `const std::string&` might be a more appropriate type for function parameters as it is typically more efficient. (Unless your function mutates the strings.)